# How to add certain CSS to middle elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div {
            padding: 10px;
            border: solid 2px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        div + div {
            border-radius: 0px;
        }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is the output:

[image]

but I am trying to get this:

[image]

Please note there isn't any certain parent with special `ID` or `class` or even `tag type`; then I can't use `first-child` and `last-child` selectors.

And also, I can't use (and I don't want to use) special classes for middle elements or corners. I am just wondering to know if there is any way to have it without using classes and in unlimited number of same elements close to each other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for sure you will have a container or there will be other element as siblings? whataver random the structure is for sure there is some particularities

Comment: Can you change the HTML? Add elements between? Add any container?

Comment: `then I can't use first-child and last-child selectors.`--> no need any class, tag, ID to use them, so they can always be used whataver the HTML you have

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, there will be other elements (of other types) as siblings

Comment: can you show an example with all the constraint?

Comment: @ItayGal it is a fixed structure and just the number of elements will change. no more elements will add in between except the same type. and there is no certain container. it will appear in the same way (with less or more elements) in other places of the document.

Comment: If it's a fixed structure, why not set a certain container. Anyway, it seems you already got an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hacky way with only `+` selector and no need `nth-*` selectors and it can work with any contiguous set of elements with the same type.

You may have to adjust the different values used within pseudo elements depending on the situation:

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div + div:before,
div + div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  width: 8px;
  border: 2px solid;
  background: #fff;
}

div + div:before {
  border-left: 0;
  right: calc(100% + 4px);
}

div + div:after {
  border-right: 0;
  left: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<span>--</span>

<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>

<span>--</span>

<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>

<span>---</span>

<div>1</div>
```

In case you will have only one contiguous set of elements with the same type within the container you can try this. The trick is to avoid the shorthand version of `border-radius` so that it can work with one element:

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

div:last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <span>---</span>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <span>---</span>
</section>
<section>
  <span>---</span>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <span>---</span>
</section>
<section>
  <span>---</span>
  <div>1</div>
  <span>---</span>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could do like this:

```
div {
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div + div {
  border-radius: 0;
}
div + div:last-of-type {
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

Or depending on the situation maybe even simpler like this:

```
div {
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div:first-of-type {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
div:last-of-type {
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: if he cannot use last-child, I doubt he can use `last-of-type` ... if we can you can then consider first-of-type also

Comment: I believe he thought he couldn't because it's necessary a parent. Also, I don't think there is another simple way.

Comment: you can still simplify this `div + div:last-of-type` to this `div:last-of-type` to make it working with 2 elements unless it won't work

Comment: This answer is not working with just one div. is it a way to fix it for one div?